# Strange image of concentric circles…magnetic field?

Tags: theory

I woke up to find a series of "images" on the window of my kitchen slider.
They were concentric circles.  They appear to be images of a magnetic field.
I was trying to link a photo of them onto this site, but was not successful
I will try

[image: concentric circles]

Comment: That looks more like the imprint of a suction cup or something similar to me. Even if something were responding to magnetic fields, they wouldn't likely be perfectly circular in cross-section — and there's nothing to produce such a localized field. That said, you haven't actually asked a specific question here. Please clarify what specifically you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Those look like marks left behind by the suction cup carriers that windows installers use to carry and install plates and complete windows. They became visible because the lighting and condensation was just right.

(And yes, terribly off-topic.)